# Show that $U=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \notin \mathbb{Z}, y \notin \mathbb{Z}\}$ is open

Tags: general-topology

I know I have to construct a ball centered at any point in $U$. However, I can only obtain the radius of that ball geometrically.

Taking a point $(a,b)$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}.$
I considered $(a+h,b+k)$ as the center of the ball where $0<h,k<1.$
This led me to think that $r=\min\{h,1-h,k,1-k\}$ could work as the radius.

I am not sure how to write a proof for this.

If I take an arbitrary element $(x,y)\in B((a+h,b+k),r),$
then, $(x-(a+h))^2+(y-(b+k))^2<r^2.$

If I let $r=h$ (to approach this by case work?)
I got,
$$x^2+a^2+2ah-2x(a+h)+(y-(b+k))^2<0$$
$$\implies (x-a)^2+2h(a-x)+(y-(b+k))^2<0$$

Now, if $(a-x)>0,$ then we get a contradiction.
Thus, $(a-x)<0.$

After this, I am not sure how to show that $x<a+1$ as well.

I would appreciate it if you could also help me understand what is required of me for this question:
(Prove that $U$ is open) $U=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 +y^2\neq 1\}$

Comment: You can certainly do it the way you're doing it, but it is tedious.  It is easier to show that the complement of $U$ in $\mathbb R^2$ is closed.

Comment: I suggest you first remove the point $(a+h, b+k)$ since it is not necessary. Instead, you should use $(x, y)$ as the center of the ball and pick $r$ such that the ball is contain inside $U$. Draw a picture first.

Comment: @D_S I thought it was always easier to show the complement is open than to show that the complement is closed. Unless your complement is very trivial.

Comment: See my edits for proper MathJax (and LaTeX) usage. In particular, the entire expression $$ U=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \notin \mathbb{Z}, y \notin \mathbb{Z}\}U=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \notin \mathbb{Z}, y \notin \mathbb{Z}\} $$ is in MathJax. The $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ should not be excluded from MathJax.

Comment: @JackyChong generally I'd agree but I think here I think showing the complement is closed is easier.  You can read my answer and see if you agree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier approach than the way you're doing it is to show that $X = \mathbb Z^2$ is closed in $\mathbb R^2$.

Suppose that $x_n \in X$ is a convergent sequence with limit $x$.  To show that $X$ is closed, you must show that $x$ lies in $X$.

Since $x_n$ is convergent, the terms in the sequence eventually get very close together.  To be more precise, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that $|x_n - x_{n+1}| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$.

Distinct points in $X$ are at least distance $1$ apart.  Taking $\epsilon = 1$, we see that $|x_n - x_{n+1}| < 1$ implies that actually $x_n = x_{n+1}$.  In other words, eventually the sequence $x_1, x_2, x_3, ...$ becomes constant!  Thus its limit $x$ remains an element of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,  $\mathbb Z×\mathbb Z $ is closed.   For it has no limit points.

---

For part two, $U=f^{-1}(\mathbb R\setminus \{1\}) $ for the continuous  $f (x,y)=x^2+y^2$.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your answer for part two but maybe we have not reached that part of our course yet. I am trying it by forming two cases for $x^2+y^2$ with the first being strictly lesser than $1$ and the other strictly greater than $1$. Thank you for your help!

Comment: well yeah, $\mathbb R\setminus\{1\}=(-\infty,1)\cup(1,\infty)$ is open.  the union of two open sets, or the complement of a point (which is closed).  either way.  note that points are closed in a metric space.